# Barcode scanner app parses barcode string to URL

Tags: android, if-statement, pattern-matching

I'm trying to build an app for learning purposes. It's a simple QR code and Barcode scanner app with a two flows:

1. If the pattern of the scan is an URL open the browser
2. If the pattern is not an URL open the browser with google.com/+string from the scan.

I have achieved goal number one with the if statement

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    final String myResult = result.getText();
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
    Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).matches()) {
        //  Open URL
        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }
}
```

My challenge is now with goal number to which I just can't get to compile. I was thinking using an else statement and parse Uri with something like google.com + the string. The expected result is that if the scanner returns and value which is not a URL pattern open the browser go to google and search with the return value.

I hope I make myself clear. Pretty much a newbie here - trying to learn terminology and way to communicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply put this else condition code in your else condition or use complete code

```
public void handleResult(Result result) { 

final String myResult = result.getText();
Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

 if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).matches()) {
    //  Open URL
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
 }
 else{
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);  
     intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, result.getText());    
     startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

Hope it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
public void handleResult(Result result) {
final String myResult = result.getText();
Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getText());
Log.d("QRCodeScanner", result.getBarcodeFormat().toString());

if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(result.getText()).matches()) {
    //  Open URL
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(result.getText()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);
}
else
{
 String scannedResult = result.getText().toString();
 String url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="+scannedResult;
 Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
 startActivity(browserIntent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to meet your requirement.

```
String query=result.getText(); 
    if(Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(query).matches()) {
            //  Open URL
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse(result.getText()));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
        }else{
            //Open url with google query
            String escapedQuery = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + escapedQuery);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
```